# how to convert bytes to buffer in python

Tags: python-3.x

i'm retrive a blob from mssql server which is showing something like this

```
b'%PDF-1.7\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-GB) /StructTreeRoot 30 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 820 0 R/ViewerPreferences 821 0 R>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Pages/Count 3/Kids[
            3 0 R 18 0 R 25 0 R
        ] >>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</XObject<</Image5 5 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS6 6 0 R/GS9 9 0 R>>/Font<</F1 7 0 R/F2 10 0 R/F3 12 0 R/F4 14 0 R/F5 16 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI
        ] >>/MediaBox[
            0 0 595.44 841.68
        ] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 7807>>\r\nstream\r\nx\x9c\xcd
    ]ms\xdc6\x92\xfe\xee*\xff\x07~\xba\x9a\xd9=Q\x04\xdf\xb9\xb5\xb7U\x8e\x9d\xb7\xdd8qb\xed\xa6R\xc9~P\xa4\x91\xadD\x96|\x92\xbc[\xfe\xf7\xd7\xddh\x80\x04\x89\x060\xc3\xf1\xdd\xa5\xca\x13I\xec\xe9~\xd8h4\x1a\x0f@\xf0\xf4\xd9\xfd\xe3\xf5\xd5\xf9\xc5c\xf6\xe7?\x9f>{|<\xbfx\xbb\xbb\xcc~>=\xbb{\xff\xcf\xd3\xb3\x8f\xefw\xa7\xaf\xce\xdf\\\xdf\x9e?^\xdf\xdd\x9e\xbe\xfe\xf0\xeb#\xfe\xe9\xab\xdd\xf9\xe5\xee\xfe/\x7f\xc9>{\xf1<;\xfd\xf2u\x9b\xbdyx\xfa\xe4\xbf\x9f>)\xb2"/
```

when i print the type of above blob it shows `bytes` i want to convert to buffer which is some thing like this `{"type":"Buffer","data":[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,55,13,10,37,181,181,181,181,13,10,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,10,60,60,47,84,121,112,101,47,67,97,116,97,108,111,103,47,80,97,103,101,115,32,50,32,48,32,82,47,76,97,110,103,40,101,110,45,71,66,41,32,47,83,116,114,117,99,116,84,114,101,101,82,111,111,116,32,51,48,32,48,32,82,47,77,97,114,107,73,110,102,111,60,60,47,77,97,114,107,101,100,32,116,114,117,101,62,62,47,77,101,116,97,100,97,116,97,32,56,50,48,32,48,32,82,47,86,105,101,119,101,114,80,114,101,102,101,114,101,110,99,101,115,32,56,50,49,32,48,32,82,62,62,13,10,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,10,50,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,10,60,60,47,84,121,112,101,47,80,97,103,101,115,47,67,111,117,110,116,32,51,47,75,105,100,115,91,32,51,32,48,32,82,32,49,56,32,48,32,82,32,50,53,32,48,32,82,93,32,62,62,13,10,101,110,100,111,98,106,13,10,51,32,48,32,111,98,106,13}` ..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have the equivalent of a "[Buffer](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer)" type, which is solely a Node.js invention. However, if you want to export the `bytes` object as JSON in a Node.js-compatible way, you could use the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = b'hello' # your data goes here
>>> json.dumps({ 'type': 'Buffer', 'data': list(data) })
'{"type": "Buffer", "data": [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]}'
```